# Globally defined array

Tags: perl

Is it bad practice to globally define an array, fill it with a subroutine, and then access it in another part of the script? E.g.,

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @people = qw( Ted Bill Tom);
my @names;

&main;

sub main{
    foreach(@people){
        &fillNames;
    }
}

sub fillNames {

    undef @names;
    print "$_\n";
    push(@names,$_);


    }
```

In the above case, I could have just had the subroutine return the array, but in my program I do this with multiple arrays (as far as I know, a subroutine can't return multiple arrays).

Another way I have seen this done is to create a file, have the subroutine print the contents of the array for each index to the file and then have the main subroutine access that file. Is that a better way to do it?

Comment: I would return a list of array references before I'd resort to a global array.

Comment: If you want to empty an array, please use `@names = ();`

Comment: `@names = get_names();` would be better, and would also remove the need for a global.

Comment: Short answer:  Don't rely on globals for anything but constants.  Always pass parameters and return values.  This will lead you to much better design for your programs including better readability and maintainability.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason globals are generally avoided is that you can easily suffer 'pollution' - the more variables, modified by more sources makes it very hard to track a broken piece of code.

For a short script, you're generally fine.

I would really avoid using idioms like `&fillnames;` though. That's doing something that you may not entirely expect. Calling a sub with in that way 'passes through' implict variables, which isn't a good style (in my opinon).

Instead:

```
foreach my $person ( @people ) {
   fillNames ( $person ); 
 }
```

subroutines can't return multiple arrays, you're right. Well, sort of - it returns a flat list, and concatenates the elements. If you want to return multiple arrays, you need to do it by reference.

E.g.:

```
sub return_two_arrays {

  my @array1 = ( "one", "two", "three" );
  my @array2 = ( "four", "five", "six" );
  return ( \@array1, \@array2 );
}

my ( $array1_ref, $array2_ref ) = return_two_arrays();
print join ( "\n", @$array1_ref );
```

As a point of note though - your code undefines @names, and then pushes a value into it. That's probably not what you want to do - and is exactly the sort of problem that using 'globals' can cause. Because as it is, you'll only ever have the last 'name' in @names.

Comment: I can see now that it's better to avoid global variables. Originally, I thought it would be best to use them because it requires fewer overall lines of code--I'm beginning to see that that's not always the best thing, however

Comment: Fewer lines doesn't always mean better code, in the same way as a shorter post isn't always the clearest way of explaining what you mean. It is _far_ better to have a page of code that's clear and obvious than one of those compressed 'one liners' that perl is notorious for.  The real strength of perl is it's flexibility - if you're not using that to make beautiful and clear code, you're doing it wrong.

Answer (score 1):

There's no cut and dry answer here, but I would say it depends on the size and scope of the script.

If your script is small enough that it's easy to keep track of globals, then I'd say it's no problem.  However, once you go above a certain size and level of complexity, I'd be wary about using a global array in this way.

Comment: For the typical beginner programmer, if they are making a subroutine that just relies on globals, the code probably doesn't deserve to be a subroutine anyway but just inline code.  I'd say the size and complexity limit you describe should be 2 lines, and that we should always just advise new programmers to pass parameters and return values.